# How i can make this function in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am in a bootcamp and i got stuck here, i tried to do it by myself and it didn't worked, then i copy and paste the code that the mentor wrote, and is not working also for some reason, i should get a random color into the gamePattern variable.. any ideas ?
Thank you.

```
var buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];

var gamePattern = [];

function nextSequence() {

  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  var randomChosenColour = buttonColours[randomNumber];
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColour);
```

Comment: You have to actually call the function.

Comment: and youre missing a closing `}` in your example code

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**"It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough** to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief **but descriptive summary of your problem** as the title of your question."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in your code `nextSequence` is missing a closing bracket `}` and you would need call the function `nextSequence()` at the end to actually execute your logic.

However, I'd recommend to avoid functions that change values of the global scope because this easily becomes a pitfall for untraceable errors and application behavior. Therefore, I'd recommend to have this helper function `randomChoiceFromList` that gives you a random item from a list. Furthermore, as it is more abstract it is potentially reusable.

```js
var buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var gamePattern = [];

function randomChoiceFromList(list) {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (list.length));
  return list[randomNumber];
};

gamePattern.push(randomChoiceFromList(buttonColours));
console.log(gamePattern);
```